# disable adding of <p></p> tags in fckeditor

Tags: fckeditor

how to disable automatic adding of `<p></p>` tags in Fckeditor.

When i try to get any post data from fckeditor, it gives me the data wrapped in

how do i remove/disable those `<p></p>`

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and reply

Comment: is it similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503655/fckeditor-displays-the-formating-characters-along-with-text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Too late, but will help others reaching this page via search engines, like I found it.

```
<?php
include_once('fckeditor/fckeditor.php');
$oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('description');
$oFCKeditor->BasePath = '/fckeditor/';
$oFCKeditor->Value = 'some text';
$oFCKeditor->Config['EnterMode'] = 'br'; // turn off auto <p> tags wrapping content
$oFCKeditor->Create();
?>
```

Refer http://www.tequilafish.com/2008/09/12/fckeditor-remove-p-tags-from-wrapping-your-content/

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answer, If you're using ColdFusion rich text area (which used fckeditor), you can disable the `<p>` tags by setting `EnterMode` to `br` in `fckconfig.js`