# FCKeditor: displays the formating characters along with text

Tags: format, fckeditor

have a form that uses  FCKeditor. I can input with formatting, but when I bring back what I put in FCKeditor it also displays the raw html format syntax.  I.E.

<p>&lt;p&gt;&amp;
Question:  is there a setting I'm missing that uses the formatting to format the text instead of displaying the formatting syntax along with the text?
thanks
Randy

Answer (score 0):

i dont know whether you are using ASP.net C# or not but if yes then first import

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using FredCK.FCKeditorV2;
```

these two things and then where you are retrieving your value from fckeditor then use

```
string fckContent = Regex.Replace(FCKEditorID.value, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
```