# FCKeditor wrapping certain HTML5 elements with <p> tags - causing problems for older browsers

Tags: html, xhtml, fckeditor

I'm being forced to use a WYSIWYG editor on a CMS our website is being published on, and the default behavior for white space is blank `<p></p>` tags (this is expected).

```
FCKeditor.prototype.Version         = '2.6' ;
FCKeditor.prototype.VersionBuild    = '18638' ;
```

That's fine, but the big problem is that the editor does not seem to recognize HTML5 elements as independent, block elements, and is wrapping `<section>`, `<aside>`, and other HTML5 tags inside `<p>...</p>` containers!

The `DOCTYPE` the CMS pages use is "XHTML Transitional," something I have no control over. However, I have declared in my custom CSS that all the HTML5 elements I'm using should display as block elements, and I've even included an HTML5shiv.js helper script to extend support for these elements to older browsers.

For instance:

```
This is a paragraph. <!-- using SHIFT+ENTER in the WYSIWYG -->
This should be a new line in the paragraph. <!-- using ENTER in the WYSIWYG -->


<section>
    <article>Some block text</article>
</section>
```

is becoming:

```
<p>This is a paragraph.<br/> <!-- using SHIFT+ENTER in the WYSIWYG -->
This should be a new line in the paragraph.</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p><section><article>Some block text</article></section></p>
```

as soon as the Save button is pressed.

First of all, what will modern vs. older browsers do when they see a `<section>` inside a `<p>` tag? How do they adjust the DOM for this situation? I explored the final DOM on the page for all modern browsers including IE9+, and they seem to ignore the errant container `<p>...</p>` tags, and/or close them before the HTML5 elements are parsed.

However, when viewing on Android's Mobile 2.1 Browser (only 2.1), and IE7 and earlier, the behavior is all over the place.

Knowing that:

1. I do **not** have any access to modify the FCKeditor files as [this post explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339319/disable-adding-of-p-p-tags-in-fckeditor).
2. I do **not** have access to configure the WYSIWYG editor the CMS is using nor update it
3. I can only run `<script type="text/javascript">` scripts, **no `PHP` is allowed**.

How do I solve this problem for those older browsers that are having trouble?

Comment: I have seen this before with various WYSIWYG editors. Might not be issue with FCKEditor, but the browser's WYSIWYG implementation. The common solution is to post-process user inputed HTML either in Javascript or on the server-side using PHP HTML libraries.

Comment: Any good post-processing javascript solutions you would suggest?

Comment: It is not difficult to do yourself using jQuery DOM manipulation functions http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Comment: It's not difficult no, but you should not be required to write a script to unwrap elements when using a text editor plugin.

Comment: As other suggests. Write a simple JavaScript code, bind it to your "Save" button click event, read whole contents of text field, where you have your FCKEditor and use .each() or any other jQuery's iteration function to read through it and remove, whatever you find not necessary. With this, anything that process your form, should receive field contents purged of any unnecessary paragraphs etc.

Comment: I cannot bind or edit any of the Editor code. This is a closed CMS platform. It would be like trying change or add code to StackOverflow's WYSIWYG editor. What I might be able to do however is process out the bad HTML from within the HTML by including said `<script>` elements in the saved content, since Javascript is allowed in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Older browsers will treat the HTML5 elements as an inline element with the DOM:

```
<p>
  <section>...</section>
</p>
```

Modern browsers will separate the `<p>` tags into two sections resulting in DOM:

```
<p></p>
<section>...</section>
<p></p>
```

With this in mind, you can detect if the parent of the `section` is `p` if not remove the excess `<p>`. http://jsfiddle.net/kJzSs/1/

```
var sections=document.getElementsByTagName('section');
for(var i=0;i<sections.length;i++){
   if(sections[i].parentNode.localName!='p'){
      sections[i].previousElementSibling.remove();
      sections[i].nextElementSibling.remove();
   }
}
```

to be a bit more careful, it may be good to add a check before removing the siblings, something like:

```
if(sections[i].previousElementSibling.localName=='p')

if(sections[i].previousElementSibling.textContent=='')
```

Comment: This technically would work, but tagging every element after every time the end users create/edit content is untenable. However, there probably is, as others suggest, a more generic, id-less way of targeting and comparing these elements.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I decided to just "flatten" stuff by using `'display: inline !important'` any `<p>` elements **not** inside `<article>` elements. Easy way out, I suppose!